# Conditional compilation is turned off

Tags: javascript

I get a javascript error:

Conditional compilation is turned off

I found this link to fix : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y5529x3(VS.90).aspx
But after adding this field

/*@cc_on @*/

I get new, another javascript error:

Expected ')'

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: ???   Could you provide more explanation?

Comment: In which browser are you getting this?  Does your HTML page have a doctype?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great piece of code, influenced by [Dean Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2007/03/sniff/), to determine whether or not conditional comments are enabled:

```
var allowsCC = /*@cc_on!@*/!1;
if(allowsCC)
  alert("Conditional comments are allowed!!!");
else
  alert("Conditional comments are not allowed.");
```

As you may have already determined, allowsCC will be set to a boolean value which indicates whether or not conditional comments are allowed.