# javascript error - conditional compilation

Tags: javascript

I am getting "Conditional compilation is turned off" javascript error. How to overcome this

```
var userName=prema.a.anchor@up.org -error in this line
if( userName == null ){
window.location = '/Mike/displayIpd.action';
}
```

Comment: I don't know what that is, but shouldn't `userName` be an actual string?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955842/conditional-compilation-is-turned-off

Comment: I highly suggest to go learn some basics before touching any serious code.

Comment: i am assigning this username variable value from session. I am checking this mail id is null or not.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be in `''` or `""` to make it a string.

`var userName = 'prema.a.anchor@up.org';`

However, since you just defined and initialized the `userName` variable, there is no need to check for `null`, and you can just remove the code below since it will never execute.

Comment: If i remove that condtion, If the username value is null from session, How can i handle it?

Comment: @user1548353, In your example you had the value hardcoded. If the value comes from the session, that is another story...

Comment: It is not the hardcoded value. i took this piece of code from view source in IE. the value is actually comes from Session. Now how can i handle it if it is empty

Comment: @user1548353, You will have to output `null` or `''` if the value is `null` in the session to avoid ending up with `var userName = ;`